# Is the pointer to data on the heap deleted when it goes out of scope?

Tags: c++

I have always heard that an anonymous temporary is allocated on the stack and it gets destroyed at the end of the evaluation of the containing expression.

So if we have the following:

```
//A function defined as 

int foo(int* p)
{ ... 
  // writing this explicitly to avoid confusion with the question
  delete p;
}

int main()
{
  foo(new int); // anonymous pointer?

  return 0;
}
```

Now when foo is called as from main(), the anonymous pointer to the heap element is copied to p, which means there are two pointers to the same heap element. Even if we do end up using delete in foo to delete the data and set the pointer to nullptr, we are still left with the anonymous pointer pointing to garbage. Are anonymous pointers like this cleared when it goes out of scope?

The situation is similar to using the shared_ptr's constructor form that also takes raw anonymous pointer from the caller to some data to construct a shared pointer where the pointer value is copied to the constructor. Are such anonymous pointers set to NULL when they go out of scope?

Comment: It's important to understand that though `delete` takes a pointer, the operation is actually performed on the memory it points *to*. So if you have two (or three, or four, or *n*) pointers all pointing to the same dynamically-allocated object, as long as `delete` is called on one of them, you won't leak memory.

Comment: When it goes out of scope, it is gone.  Can't be named.  Trying (for example by using a reference bound to it beforehand) is undefined behavior.  So it's meaningless to ask whether its value is a NULL pointer or that.  The pointer value doesn't exist.

Comment: Pair new with a delete, or delegate ownership to a std::unique_ptr/std::shared_ptr (there is no automatic deletion of a pointer)

Comment: Setting a pointer to `nullptr` after deleting it is good practice *under some circumstances* since it makes it obvious the pointer is no longer valid, but it is not required for correct memory management. Or in other words, in C++, setting a pointer to null has no effect on the thing it points to. This is unlike C# and Java where doing the same thing *may* make the object a candidate for garbage collection.

Comment: People are confused by your question because they think you mean the delete does not exist there. With your code as written, it does NOT cause a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks Neil. Yes. However I just want to know if the anonymous pointer is cleared or what happens to itself when it goes out of scope. I am not interested in the data it is pointing to when I wrote this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I smell a misconception in your question. However, I might be wrong about that; if so disregard.

You ask this:

> Even if we do end up using delete in foo to delete the data and set
>   the pointer to nullptr, we are still left with the anonymous pointer
>   pointing to garbage. Are anonymous pointers like this cleared when it
>   goes out of scope?
>
> The situation is similar to using the shared_ptr's constructor form
>   that also takes raw anonymous pointer from the caller to some data to
>   construct a shared pointer where the pointer value is copied to the
>   constructor. Are such anonymous pointers set to NULL when they go out
>   of scope?

From those questions, it seems like you might be under the impression that setting a pointer to null ("clearing" it) is an essential part of freeing whatever it points to. In C++, this is not the case. To free the object `p` points to, you do `delete p;`, end of story. You *may* also say `p = nullptr;` afterwards if you want to ensure anyone who looks at `p` later realizes it's invalid, but whether you do or not, the object it pointed to before is gone.

So in this hypothetical code:

```
int foo(int* p)
{
   //some content
   delete p;
}

int main()
{
  foo(new int); // anonymous pointer?
}
```

no memory is leaked, and everything is fine. The question of whether the temporary, anonymous pointer passed to `foo` is referencing garbage after `foo` returns is meaningless, since the temporary is effectively invisible at that point and does not further participate in anything the program does (raw pointers don't have destructors).

But in *this* hypothetical code:

```
int foo(int* p)
{
   //some content, but no delete p
}

int main()
{
  foo(new int); // anonymous pointer?
}
```

Nothing will delete the anonymous `new int`, so you have a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your comment. What I meant by delete was not about the data pointed to by the pointer. I meant to ask if the pointer itself is deleted when the temporary goes out of scope.

Comment: @avish The pointer is on the stack and so does not need to be deleted. In general, if you don't use `new`, it's all good.

Comment: Exactly. A pointer is just a number; what happens to one when it goes out of scope is the same thing that happens to an `int`.

Comment: Now if you had written `foo(*(new int*) = new int);`, that would leak an `int*`, but that would be a very strange thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

No, they're not automatically deleted.  Objects and POD allocated with automatic storage are.  Objects or POD allocated with `new` are not.

> we are still left with the anonymous pointer pointing to garbage. Are anonymous pointers like this cleared when it goes out of scope?

It's anonymous, so there's no defined behavior for what the value could contain.  Pointers are a C++ and C concept, so the intermediates used by the compiler aren't described by any standard.  But if you want to know what happens with your compiler, you can disassemble the object code.  It's likely that the value that represented the pointer may have been stored on the stack and will get reaped (the pointer itself, not the `int` pointed to) when `main` returns.

Comment: Nothing to do with PODs. All automatic storage objects are "deleted".

Comment: Besides `No, they're not automatically deleted` the answer is useless.

Answer (score 0):

No. A pointer is not a shared pointer and is not automatically deleted by default in C++.

```
void fn()
{
    YourClass LocalObject;
    ... 
} // LocalObject goes out of scope here and is destroyed automatically

void fn2()
{
    YourClass *PointedObject = new YourClass();
} // Object pointed to by the pointer is not destroyed.
```

In reality `PointedObject` would need deleting at some point. You'd probably return the pointer or something and call `delete` when you're done with it.