# Can we stop a std::list from tidying up memory?

Tags: c++, stdlist

I defined this list:

```
using SpecialEventList = list<SPECIAL_EVENT_S*>;
```

The items are added to this list like this:

```
m_listNewSpecialEvents.push_back(psEvent);
```

The original list of `SPECIAL_EVENT_S` pointers is owned and managed by another list help in the app class.

My concern is that when this dialog closes that `m_listNewSpecialEvents` will automatically delete the pointers and I don' want it to.

Can we stop this list from tidying up the memory?

Comment: *will automatically delete the pointers* Why do you think so?

Comment: @songyuanyao I always understood that a std::list will tidy itself.

Comment: It does, but it will never `delete` pointers. It's only the memory occupied by the pointers that it will clean up.

Comment: @TedLyngmo So my original pointers / content will remain intact.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, so does `std::vector`. So what?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yes, the memory they point at will be unharmed by the `list` being destroyed

Comment: Normally you don't have pointers in the list, you would have a `list<SPECIAL_EVENT_S>`.

Comment: @super Understood. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't delete pointers unless you explicitly delete them. raw pointers don't get deleted automatically. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243640/is-the-pointer-to-data-on-the-heap-deleted-when-it-goes-out-of-scope)